# Python if statements

Tags: python

I am new to Python

I have a `if: else` statement.

my problem : right now after print "Welcome to the Script" my script exits ,  but I want it exits just after else and also when my condition was true continue to line `name=raw_input("Enter your name: ")` and so on not exit ...

How can I exit from the if else and continue in the script?

```
script_username="test" 
script_password="1"        
login_username=raw_input('Please Enter the script username:')
login_password=getpass.getpass('Please Enter the script password:')

if login_password == script_password and login_username == script_username:
    print "Welcome to the Script" 

else:
    print "your Username or Password is false"
    exit()


name=raw_input("Enter your name: ")
family=raw_input("Enter your family: ")
sex=raw_input("Enter your Sex: ")
print "hello " + sex + name + family
raw_input("press<enter>")
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly

Comment: Python depends on indentation to know the block structure of your script. If you don't indent correctly, it won't work.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that (see the new indention)

```
script_username="test" 
script_password="1"        
login_username=raw_input('Please Enter the script username:')
login_password=getpass.getpass('Please Enter the script password:')

if login_password == script_password and login_username == script_username:
    print "         Welcome to the Script           " 
else:
    print "     your Username or Password is false      "
    exit()

name=raw_input("Enter your name: ")
family=raw_input("Enter your family: ")
sex=raw_input("Enter your Sex: ")
print "hello " + sex + name + family
raw_input("press<enter>")
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Correcting the indentation should be an edit to the original post, not a new answer.

Comment: IMO his problem is his wrong indention - therefore fixing the indention is the answer to his problem. If you edit the question so that his indention is correct - well, then there is no problem any longer

Comment: again, this is not work -- i corrected indention but after print Welcome to the script it exits and not continue

Comment: Please watch out for the indention. I just tested this code on my machine (slightly adjusted for python3) and it worked.
Try replacing all Tabs with four spaces

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem.  `getpass.getpass('prompt')` doesn't return a string.  Either fix that or use this:

```
script_username="test" 
script_password="1"        
login_username=raw_input('Please Enter the script username:')
login_password=raw_input('Please Enter the script password:')

if login_password == script_password and login_username == script_username:
    print "         Welcome to the Script           " 
else:
    print "     your Username or Password is false      "
    exit()

name=raw_input("Enter your name: ")
family=raw_input("Enter your family: ")
sex=raw_input("Enter your Sex: ")
print "hello " + sex + name + family
raw_input("press<enter>")
```

Output:

```
Please Enter the script username:test
Please Enter the script password:1
     Welcome to the Script           
Enter your name: Louis
Enter your family: Mom, Dad, Dog
Enter your Sex: Male
hello MaleLouisMom, Dad, Dog
press<enter>
```

**IMPORTANT**

This block:

```
name=raw_input("Enter your name: ")
family=raw_input("Enter your family: ")
sex=raw_input("Enter your Sex: ")
print "hello " + sex + name + family
raw_input("press<enter>")
```

was indented incorrectly in your question.  It should be at the level below (i.e. no spaces) the stuff in the if statement.  This would also break your program (because it'd think everything was in the `if` statement.

**EDIT 2:** Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: dear Louis, i dont have any problem with getpass, my problem is : why after print Welcome the script, it exits , whereas i expect to go "name=raw_input......" line

Comment: Have you tried this?  It worked exactly as expected on my machine.

Comment: The *only* important thing is the location of the `exit()`.  If it is at the same indentation level as the rest of the things in the `else:` block it should work.

Comment: @Farsanet check my most recent edit

Comment: I don't know, I'm confusing about indention.

Comment: @Farsanet Just copy and paste the first block of code I posted into your document.  Try this online interpreter if you need to try things.  I'll post a screenshot of what I mean. You run scripts using the triangle button. http://repl.it/languages/Python

Comment: It works-- Thanks to all - my problem was about indent as all of you, pointed. thanks again.